# Performance issues running Linux Mint on qemu-kvm - maybe run in textmode and use remote graphics for administration?

Tags: linux-mint, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

We are running virtual servers on KVM-Qemu, using Debian Wheezy as a host system. Unfortunately one server is based on Linux Mint 17.3.

One big issue is the performance of Linux Mint running on KVM. Linux Mint is probably not meant to be a server system at all (3d-grapfic effects et cetera).

The Linux kernel only supports 3d-virtualization in a newer kernel, as far as I know, and our servers only have limited onboard graphics either.

We will try to change that later, but for now this is the status quo and we need a fast solution. The main application is java based and our consulting partner uses TeamViewer for remote administration (yet).

I recognized that running LM in text mode gives much higher performance to the clients:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

As far as I know, you can run Linux in text mode like this, but use another machine for graphical administration. I imagine to set up a lightweight distribution like Xfce in another virtual machine to keep the system load on Mint low.

Could you give me any hints on this? Would it be easy to set up or impossible?

Any other recommendations for our performance problems are also highly appreciated, as our go-live is planned to be very soon.

Or do you think  a newer KVM versions would solve our performance problems?

Comment: By all means, try remote graphics. ssh with compression and X forwarding is one way, or remote desktop protocol.